# Possible methods of solving this question, understanding this captcha

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, captcha

**Keep in mind that this is a challenge, I am not expecting a full answer, just a bit of help.**

On the image archived you are able to see a complex captcha that I am attempting to solve using code.

[image: 1]

The captcha has a column for # and another composed of a random string.

The captcha itself is actually identifying which string row has the **different** color in it, once you identify that then you can input the # of that string row.

For the image below the string row #4. has a smaller portion of str colored differently, and #4 is the correct answer.

How could I solve this programmatically?

I thought of using AI but I think that is overkill, I should be able to do this with OpenCV.

*Note*: The background is also a random image, it can be anything.
Fortuntely, the foreground is very noticeable and clear making it easy to ignore the background with code

I am mostly researching possible methods of solving this captcha, fortunately I think I'm on the right path, which involves using OpenCV, but I'm not sure which functionalities of OpenCV I should use for this.

The challenge requires the app to return an integer, in this case it is the # of the correct 'messed' up string.

Comment: For each row you could count the number of different colours. This way you can detect the different text lines and also the line where the colour differs. If you need more help, please start to code and share a minimal reproducible code with a specific problem. [ask]

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. show your own attempt. use opencv documentation to learn about the library and image processing in general. -- @Joshua "hex code"? that's not a word that occurs in actual image processing. if you mean to say that OP should work with pixel values... I would consider that implied in the question.